# Summing rows in grouped pandas dataframe and return NaN

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, nan

## Example

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
d = {'l':  ['left', 'right', 'left', 'right', 'left', 'right'],
     'r': ['right', 'left', 'right', 'left', 'right', 'left'],
     'v': [-1, 1, -1, 1, -1, np.nan]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

## Problem

When a grouped dataframe contains a value of `np.NaN` I want the grouped sum to be `NaN` as is given by the `skipna=False` flag for [`pd.Series.sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sum.html#pandas-series-sum) and also [`pd.DataFrame.sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) however, this

```
In [235]: df.v.sum(skipna=False)
Out[235]: nan
```

However, this behavior is not reflected in the [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) object

```
In [237]: df.groupby('l')['v'].sum()['right']
Out[237]: 2.0
```

and cannot be forced by applying the `np.sum` method directly

```
In [238]: df.groupby('l')['v'].apply(np.sum)['right']
Out[238]: 2.0
```

## Workaround

I can workaround this by doing

```
check_cols = ['v']
df['flag'] = df[check_cols].isnull().any(axis=1)
df.groupby('l')['v', 'flag'].apply(np.sum).apply(
    lambda x: x if not x.flag else np.nan,
    axis=1
)
```

but this is ugly. Is there a better method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it's inherent to pandas. A workaround can be :

```
df.groupby('l')['v'].apply(array).apply(sum)
```

to mimic the numpy way,

or

```
df.groupby('l')['v'].apply(pd.Series.sum,skipna=False) # for series, or
df.groupby('l')['v'].apply(pd.DataFrame.sum,skipna=False) # for dataframes.
```

to call the good function.

Comment: Worth adding that for multiple columns (ie. a DataFrame) the method changes to `.apply(pd.DataFrame.sum, skipna=False)`

Comment: For resampling this works: df['my_column'].resample('1h').apply(pd.Series.sum, skipna=False)

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure where this falls on the ugliness scale, but it works:

```
>>> series_sum = pd.core.series.Series.sum
>>> df.groupby('l')['v'].agg(series_sum, skipna=False)
l
left     -3
right   NaN
Name: v, dtype: float64
```

I just dug up the `sum` method you used when you took `df.v.sum`, which supports the `skipna` option:

```
>>> help(df.v.sum)
Help on method sum in module pandas.core.generic:

sum(axis=None, skipna=None, level=None, numeric_only=None, **kwargs) method 
of pandas.core.series.Series instance
```

Answer (score 1):

Is that what you want?

```
In [24]: df.groupby('l')['v'].agg(lambda x: np.nan if x.isnull().any() else x.sum())
Out[24]:
l
left    -3.0
right    NaN
Name: v, dtype: float64
```

or

```
In [22]: df.groupby('l')['v'].agg(lambda x: x.sum() if x.notnull().all() else np.nan)
Out[22]:
l
left    -3.0
right    NaN
Name: v, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.groupby(xxx).yyy.apply(lambda x: x.sum(skipna=False))
```