# Group by and find sum for groups but return NaN as NaN, not 0

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, nan

I have a dataframe where each unique group has 4 rows. 
So I need to group by columns that makes them unique and does some aggregations such as max, min, sum and average. 
But the problem is that I have for some group all NaN values (in some column) and returns me a 0. Is it possible to return me a NaN? 
For example:
df

```
       time            id     el    conn   column1  column2  column3
2018-02-11 14:00:00     1     a      12      8        5         NaN
2018-02-11 14:00:00     1     a      12      1        NaN       NaN
2018-02-11 14:00:00     1     a      12      3        7         NaN
2018-02-11 14:00:00     1     a      12      4        12        NaN
2018-02-11 14:00:00     2     a      5       NaN      5         5
2018-02-11 14:00:00     2     a      5       NaN      3         2
2018-02-11 14:00:00     2     a      5       NaN      NaN       6
2018-02-11 14:00:00     2     a      5       NaN      7         NaN
```

So, for example, I need to groupby ('id', 'el', 'conn') and find sum for column1, column3 and column2. (In real case I have a lot more columns need to be performed aggregation on). 
I have tried a few ways: .sum(), .transform('sum'), but returns me a zero for group with all NaN values.

Desired output:

```
    time               id    el     conn   column1  column2  column3
2018-02-11 14:00:00     1     a      12      16       24       NaN
2018-02-11 14:00:00     2     a      5       NaN      15        13
```

Any help is welcomed.

Comment: Related: [Summing rows in grouped pandas dataframe and return NaN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42770300/summing-rows-in-grouped-pandas-dataframe-and-return-nan)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change parameter `min_count` to `1` - this working in [last pandas version `0.22.0`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#arithmetic-operations):

> **min_count** : int, default 0
>
> The required number of valid values to perform the operation. If fewer than min_count non-NA values are present the result will be NA.
>
> New in version 0.22.0: Added with the default being 1. This means the sum or product of an all-NA or empty series is NaN.

```
df = df.groupby(['time','id', 'el', 'conn'], as_index=False).sum(min_count=1)
print (df)
                  time  id el  conn  column1  column2  column3
0  2018-02-11 14:00:00   1  a    12     16.0     24.0      NaN
1  2018-02-11 14:00:00   2  a     5      NaN     15.0     13.0
```

Comment: I have got: TypeError: f() got an unexpected keyword argument 'min_count'.

Comment: @jovicbg - What is your pandas version?

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. 0.19 Unfortunately, I can't upgrade because It's not local, is not depending on me.

Comment: @jovicbg - It seems more complicated, what return for you `s = Series([np.nan])` and `s.sum(skipna=True)`, `s.sum()` ?

Comment: Return me 0.0 .

Comment: @jovicbg both `s.sum(skipna=True)` and `s.sum()`?

Comment: Yes, both of them.

Comment: But this returns me nan : s.sum(skipna=False)

Comment: @jovicbg - So it working with `groupby` + `sum` too? Or not?

Comment: In that case I got an error : TypeError: f() got an unexpected keyword argument 'skipna'

Comment: Hmmm, it is not good. What about `df = df.groupby(['time','id', 'el', 'conn'], as_index=False).agg(lambda x: x.sum(skipna=True))` ?

Comment: @jovicbg - Is bottleneck installed? [link](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#sum-prod-of-all-nan-or-empty-series-dataframes-is-now-consistently-nan)

Comment: Yes, it's installed. But a few minutes ago my admin upgrade pandas to 0.22 and still remain the same.

Comment: @jovicbg - Is possible restart IDE? From version `0.22.0` solution with `min_count=1` should working nice.

Comment: O thank god. I had to exit jupyter notebook entirely and login again, now it works. Thank you very much. :)

Comment: @jovicbg - Glad can help!

Comment: Thanks! This saved my day!

Comment: Do you know how to ignore a column (i.e. ignoring it in the groupby statement) when using the lambda x function?

Comment: I am trying the following: `lambda x:ignore(x)` @jezrael

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be something like this.

```
df.groupby(['time','id','el','conn']).sum()
```

Output in Python 2:

[image]

Some little tutorial for groupby I find interesting in these cases:

1. https://chrisalbon.com/python/data_wrangling/pandas_apply_operations_to_groups/
2. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_pandas/python_pandas_groupby.htm

Comment: I can't use his because I need to specify column, there are some column that need to be used for average, min, max, etc, not just a sum.