# How can I quickly sum over a Pandas groupby object while handling NaNs?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, group-by

I have a `DataFrame` with `key` and `value` columns. `value` is sometimes NA:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'key': np.random.randint(0, 1_000_000, 100_000_000),
    'value': np.random.randint(0, 1_000, 100_000_000).astype(float),
})
    
df.loc[df.value == 0, 'value'] = np.nan
```

I want to group by `key` and sum over the `value` column. If any `value` is NA for a `key`, I want the sum to be NA.

The code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42771217/785404) takes 35.7 seconds on my machine:

```py
df.groupby('key')['value'].apply(np.array).apply(np.sum)
```

This is a lot slower than what is theoretically possible. The built-in Pandas `SeriesGroupBy.sum` takes 6.31 seconds on my machine:

```py
df.groupby('key')['value'].sum()
```

but it doesn't support NA handling (see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15675)).

What code can I write to get comparable performance to the built-in operator while still handling NaNs?

Comment: I know this is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42770300/summing-rows-in-grouped-pandas-dataframe-and-return-nan, but I'm specifically interested in performance and not just how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One workaround could be to replace the NaNs by Inf:

```
df.fillna({'value': np.inf}).groupby('key')['value'].sum().replace(np.inf, np.nan)
```

Faster alternative:

```
df['value'].fillna(np.inf).groupby(df['key']).sum().replace(np.inf, np.nan)
```

Example output:

```
key
0        45208.0
1            NaN
2        62754.0
3        50001.0
4        51073.0
          ...   
99995    55102.0
99996    43048.0
99997    49497.0
99998    43301.0
99999        NaN
Name: value, Length: 100000, dtype: float64
```

Timing (on 10m rows).

```
# original sum
743 ms ± 81 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# Inf workaround
918 ms ± 70.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# Inf workaround (alternative)
773 ms ± 60.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# custom apply with numpy
5.99 s ± 263 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: In my testing, the "faster alternative" runs in 6.14s, whereas the first suggestion takes 27.5s. So I think only the "faster alternative" is comparable to SeriesGroupBy.sum's performance. (It's actually *faster* than just SeriesGroupBy.sum; that's probably measurement noise).

I guess there is some non-linear effect going from 10 million to 100 million rows?

Comment: You should try to run a `perfplot` to see how this scales. I currently can't run beefy big tests.

Comment: You also need to do .replace(np.inf, np.nan) at the end. If there is only a single element in the group, the result of sum() will be inf rather than nan. (Really weird Pandas behavior IMO).

I submitted an edit to add the .replace.

Comment: Yes that's true!